# How to send periodically data from client to server

Tags: java, client-server

A part of my program needs to simulate a GPS. So I am setting up a client-server connection. Where on server my main application would run and on client it would send the GPS string periodically after a particular time interval. I am using JAVA for programming it and I am a bit new to networking area, so if someone can just give me an idea about How do i send my data periodically? The emphasis is on just one part. Periodically after a time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a java timer to your code that triggers at the interval you specify. In the timer handler, just run some code to send data to the server.

Answer (score 2):

you can use TimerTask Class for your solution. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/SchedulingaTimerTasktoRunRepeatedly.htm) is a very useful link for its example.

In its run method you need to deploy your uploading code.
I am also working on same kind of project right now.

Comment: Lucifer...thanks...was never aware of this class... i think i would upload my client code in the run method... let's see if that works

Comment: I was wondering if we can just use sleep or wait for the main thread... won't that work??

Answer (score 1):

Use a [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) with a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Although your requirement might be simple enough, but i suggest you take a look into [quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org).

It supports from plain simple timer tasks (like every minute or every xx seconds) to the [more complex timing scenarios](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/).

Here is [one simple example](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example1) that you can dive more deeply from the source code.

Comment: Thanks albert... i'll see to it.